# forcing gam dependent variable to be zero when independent variable is zero

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

In the lm world, one can suppress the bias by using either:

```
y ~ x + 0
```

or

```
y ~ x - 1
```

Is this possible with GAMs? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Both those options work with *mgcv* if you don't have factors in the model. If you do have factors in the model and want to get rid of the constant, `gam()` has an argument `drop.intercept`, which you can set to `TRUE` to force no constant in the parametric part of the model.

Comment: Thanks. Will check this out tomorrow 